# SQL error, incorrect implementation of group by

Tags: sql

I am practicing sql, and I came upon this problem. I am unsure of the sql logic, more specifically, it appears that I am using group by completely wrong.

Problem:
Print the name and age of the employee(s) with the highest salary among all employee of the same age.

```
employee(sid, sname, sex, age, year, salary)
```

First Attempt:

```
select E.sname, E.age
from employee E
where E.salary= max(E.salary)
group by E.sname, E.age

Error: Invalid SQL: ORA-00934: group function is not allowed here
```

Second attempt

```
select E.sname, E.age
from employee E
group by E.sname, E.age
having E.salary= max(E.salary)
Error: Invalid SQL: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
```

Comment: Use a sub-select to get the max salary.

Comment: @jarih can you explain what is wrong with my implementation?

Comment: @Sam It's not valid SQL - `WHERE` executes before grouping so you can't have an aggregation, and `HAVING` only applies to the grouping expressions or aggregations.  You have to use other methods (sub-select,  partitioning, etc) to get the records with the highest values in each group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may work:

```
select E.sname, E.age
from employee E
where E.salary=
  (select max(salary)
   from employee a
   where a.age = E.age
   )
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler approach to the problem is using analytic function `rank`.

```
select sname, age, salary 
from (
select sname, age, salary,
rank() over(partition by age order by salary desc) rnk
from employee) t
where rnk = 1
```

Or to correct the query you have

```
select E.sname, E.age, E.salary
from employee E
where (age, salary) in (select age,max(salary) from employee group by age)
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that the GROUP BY is used on fields that are not within an aggregate function, and that you cannot use aggregate functions in the WHERE clause.

```
SELECT e1.name, e1.age
  FROM employee e1, (SELECT age, MAX(salary) AS max_salary FROM employee GROUP BY age) e2
 WHERE e1.salary = e2.max_salary
   AND e1.age = e2.age;
```